# Does using Wish to cast a 7th-level spell use a 7th-level spell slot as well as the 9th-level one for Wish?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-slots, wish

The PHB says the basic use of the *Wish* spell is to duplicate the effect of any other spell of 8th level or lower without having to meet any requirements of costly components.

If, as a wizard, you wanted to use *Wish* to cast (for example) *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion*, does that mean that as well as using a 9th-level spell slot to cast *Wish*, you would also have to use a 7th-level spell slot (since *Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion* is a 7th-level spell)?

Comment: Related, sorta: "[Does Wish just give another spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133757)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No.  *Wish* uses a 9th level slot for any casting, and one of its canonical uses is to duplicate any spell (of 8th level or lower).  Consider the case of a 19th level Wizard who, for one reason or another, has expended all of their 7th and 8th level slots, and further, doesn't actually have *Mordenkainen's magnificent mansion* prepared -- but wants to cast it in order to take a safe long rest, recover their slots, and incidentally make a couple small changes to their prepared list.

They have *wish* at their disposal, and a 9th level slot -- if casting *wish* required also having a slot of the level of the spell it's duplicating, we'd have a case of the most powerful and versatile spell there is, being *unable to do one of the things it's designed to do.*

Answer (score 10):

You would only be using the 9th lv spell slot.  The wish spell does not ask you to expend any other slots.

"The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. ... The spell simply takes effect."